# IF Formula in Sharepoint Calculated field

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, error-handling

I'm trying to create a formula to get a result in a field `Status` using 2 columns info:

- Cert. Approval - text
- Cert. Validity - date

My logical reasoning is:

```
=IF([Cert. Approval]="Approved";"NA";IF([Cert. Validity]="";"NA";IF([Cert. Validity]<(TODAY());"Expired";IF([Cert.Validity]<(TODAY()+30);"Expired soon";"Valid")
```

Something is going wrong because I`m getting an error

Thanks

Comment: In order to help you solve the problem, can you describe in detail the effect you want the formula to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula like below for your calculated column:

```
=IF(OR([Cert. Approval]="Approved";ISBLANK([Cert. Validity]));"NA";IF([Cert. Validity]<TODAY();"Expired";IF([Cert.Validity]<(TODAY()+30);"Expired soon";"Valid")))
```

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.